# How can I find operating point in this curcuit?

Tags: voltage, transistors, ltspice, simulation, npn

I made a schematic in LTspice like in the first picture and then solved the question in second picture for Rb=100k.[image]

[image]

I have found Ib=0.03 mA, Ic=4.5 mA and Vce=-0.836 V but when I checked the graphic of Ic vs Vce (in the third picture), I couldn't find an operating point that matchs up with my answers. Could you help me please?

[image]

Comment: How did you get a negative Vce? By just looking at the circuit you know that must be wrong. What equations did you try and solve? There are three because you have three unknowns: Vce, Ib , Ic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s do it in parts:

```
               Vcc = Ic x Rc + Vce + Ie x Re 

                        Vce = Vc - Ve 

                          Vc = Ic x Rc

                           Ve = Ie x Re
```

- Maximum collector current as if the transistor was not there (Vce = zero):

  ```
              Vcc = Ic x Rc + zero + Ie x Re; Ic = Ie
                 10V = Ic x 1.2k + 0 + Ic x 1.2k 
                  Ic = 4.17 mA 
                  Vc = 10V - 1.2k x 4.17 mA = 5V
                  Ve = 10V - 1.2k x 4.17 mA = 5V
  ```

Conclusion: Collector current (and base current + emitter current) cannot be   higher than 4.17 mA

- Calculating Base current:

  ```
    Vcc = Ib x Rb + 0.7V + Ie x Re
     Vcc = Ib x Rb + 0.7V + (Ic + Ib) x Re
      Vcc = Ib x Rb + 0.7V + (150 x Ib + Ib) x Re
      After several transforms:
        Ib = (Vcc - 0.7V) / (Rb + 150 x Rb + Re)
  ```

1. For Rb = 300k; Ib = 0.019 mA; Ic = 2.85 mA; Vc = 6.58V; Ve = 3.44; Vce = 3.14V;
2. For Rb = 200k; Ib = 0.024 mA; Ic = 3.6 mA; Vc = 5.68V; Ve = 4.35V; Vce = 1.33V;
3. For Rb = 100k; Ib = 0.033 mA; Ic = 4.95 mA; Vc = 5.94V; Ve = 5.98V; Vce=-0.04V (negative) not possible. So with 100K base resistor the transistor must be saturated and the Vce must be almost zero, between 0.07V and 0.2V, as per datasheet.
4. For Vce = 0.2V; Ib = 0.027 mA; Ic = 4.07 mA; Vc = 5.12V; Ve = 4.92V; Vce = 0.2V;
5. For Vce = 0.07V; Ib = 0.027 mA; Ic = 4.12 mA; Vc = 5.06V; Ve = 4.98V; Vce=0.08V

Please note that the calculated values have been rounded up/down.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that we should find the maximum collector current. In the last part you have taken Rb=300k but it wasn't given in the question.

Comment: I used this method in your example to make things simple and to know what would be the maximum current and voltages first of anything else.

Comment: Sorry for the 300k resistor. I got distracted with so many equations. But you can use them to calculated for 150k resistor as well. See what you get.

Comment: PS: check your graphic again. Is it possible that the blue and green lines are the 150k and 100k base resistor values?

Comment: Yes, most probably.

Comment: @Mert To check which graph belongs to which step, use the cursors (`RClick` on the waveform's label in the waveform window), select the traces with the up/down arrow keys, then `RClick` on the cursors.

Answer (score 5):

### Preliminaries

Mert, keep at it. It's nice to see your process unfolding. It won't be long and you may be doing these things as well as many do.

To start out, most sub-circuits using a BJT will either be operating the BJT in *active* mode (which just means in the NPN case that the collector has a more positive voltage than the base, so that the collector-to-base diode junction is operated in reversed-biased mode) or else in *saturated* mode (which in the NPN case means that the collector is more negative than the base, so that the collector-to-base diode junction is operated in forward mode.) To analyze a circuit, you need to first find out which of these applies because the simplifying analysis is different for each.

The simplifying assumptions in the two cases are:

1. **Active mode**: Apply the given \$\beta\$ value as an *input* for analysis.
2. **Saturated mode**: \$\beta\$ is an *output* of the analysis, not an input to it. So here you assume that \$V_{_\text{CE}}\$ is small -- typically under a few hundred millivolts -- and then apply \$I_{_\text{E}}=I_{_\text{B}} +I_{_\text{C}}\$ for analysis.

Note that the value for \$\beta\$ applies as an input to analysis if and only if the BJT is in *active* mode. If not, then it does **not** apply.

It's common to first assume (1) above and see if that works out okay. If it does, you are done. If not, then it is usually because the collector has been forced between the base and emitter voltages (most often because the collector resistor's voltage drop makes it so) and you are in case (2) and so then you perform a different analysis.

Let's re-draw the schematic to simplify reading it before I proceed to examine each possible case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWWkO2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, let's start with (1) above:

### Active mode assumption

In this case, the collector *acts like* a current source. (Or, in this case, a current sink.) Ideally, a current source has infinite impedance. This is not the case for BJT collectors, but then the fact is also not so far from it, either. So we can reduce the circuit to this simplified case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV56Rk.png)</sup>

Note that I've simply disconnected the collector from the circuit. That's because, for these *temporary* purposes of analysis, its output impedance is infinite and it is therefore *not* actually directly connected up.

(There is a collector current there. I'm not saying there isn't. But we can just assume a collector current based upon the base current and ignore the collector resistor for now.)

There is only one KVL loop to solve here:

$$V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{B}}\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-R_{_\text{E}}\cdot I_{_\text{E}}=0\:\text{V}$$

Assuming *active* mode, the relationship \$I_{_\text{E}}=\left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_{_\text{B}}\$ holds. The value of \$\beta\$ itself will vary somewhat widely from device to device, though Spice will calculate only one value given only one BJT model to work from.

(So keep in mind that while I'll use \$\beta\$ as if it were simply some one value, that won't be true if you were to build the circuit on a protoboard.)

From the above KVL, we can apply the emitter current substitution:

$$V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{B}}\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-R_{_\text{E}}\cdot \left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_{_\text{B}}=0\:\text{V}$$

And then solve for \$ I_{_\text{B}}\$:

$$ I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{BE}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{E}}\cdot\left(\beta+1\right)}$$

You are using several values for \$R_{_\text{B}}\$. But for \$R_{_\text{B}}=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$V_{_\text{CC}}=10\:\text{V}\$ this yields \$I_{_\text{B}}\approx 33.1\:\mu\text{A}\$. Which, I see, is about what you say you got in your own calculation result.

This implies, assuming *active* mode, that the collector current is 150 times higher, or \$\approx 4.96\:\text{mA}\$. Call it \$5\:\text{mA}\$. You can multiply that by your collector resistor value to find that the voltage drop across the collector resistor is then implied to be \$\approx 6\:\text{V}\$.

But this is also about the voltage drop across the emitter resistor, too. Which means that between them both, emitter resistor and collector resistor, you'd expect about \$12\:\text{V}\$ voltage drop. Since that exceeds the maximum of your DC voltage sweep, which only goes to (at most) \$10\:\text{V}\$, there is a violation of the *active* mode assumptions. Further, while reducing \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ may reduce the currents and therefore the voltage drops, the fact is that \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ is also reduced. Therefore, when \$R_{_\text{B}}=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ it would seem that the BJT may be saturated throughout the DC sweep.

### Saturated mode

So, this moves you into a *saturated* mode assumption where \$V_{_\text{CE}}\$ is small and \$\beta\$ is no longer an input, but instead an output of the analysis.

Let's assume a value that is commonly applied, \$V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}\!\!\approx 200\:\text{mV}\$. Given that fact, we can re-draw the schematic again to find this simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFwoYe.png)</sup>

All I did here was to replace the BJT with two voltage sources. The base-emitter junction acts like a voltage source in both *active* and *saturated* modes. But now the collector-emitter **also** acts like a voltage source. So the left side shows the new relationship.

I can then simply move those voltage sources up to \$V_{_\text{CC}}\$ and subtract them there, greatly simplifying the analysis circuit shown on the right side.

Here, use KCL:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{E}}}{R_{_\text{B}}}+\frac{V_{_\text{E}}}{R_{_\text{C}}}+\frac{V_{_\text{E}}}{R_{_\text{E}}}=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_\text{BE}}}{R_{_\text{B}}}+\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}}{R_{_\text{C}}}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_{_\text{E}}}$$

Solving for \$V_{_\text{E}}\$:

$$V_{_\text{E}}=R_{_\text{E}}\cdot \frac{\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}\right)\cdot R_{_\text{B}}+\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{BE}}}\right)\cdot R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{B}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}+R_{_\text{B}}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}+R_{_\text{C}}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}}$$

Obviously, dividing that by \$R_{_\text{E}}\$ gives \$I_{_\text{E}}\$:

$$I_{_\text{E}}=\frac{\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}\right)\cdot R_{_\text{B}}+\left(V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{BE}}}\right)\cdot R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{B}}\cdot R_{_\text{C}}+R_{_\text{B}}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}+R_{_\text{C}}\cdot R_{_\text{E}}}$$

It's easy enough now to also find the remaining two currents (if you want them):

$$\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{B}} &=\frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{BE}}}-V_{_\text{E}}}{R_{_\text{C}}} &=\left[\frac{R_{_\text{C}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{C}}}\right]\cdot I_{_\text{E}}-\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{C}}}
\\\\
I_{_\text{C}} &= \frac{V_{_\text{CC}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}-V_{_\text{E}}}{R_{_\text{C}}}&=\left[\frac{R_{_\text{B}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{C}}}\right]\cdot I_{_\text{E}}+\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{C}}}
\end{align*}$$

(Above, I also decided to put the two remaining currents in terms of \$I_{_\text{E}}\$ on the right side. The last term there, \$\frac{V_{_\text{BE}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}}{R_{_\text{B}}+R_{_\text{C}}}\$, is usually quite small. So the first term just represents a simple conductance divider where the emitter current is split between \$R_{_\text{B}}\$ and \$R_{_\text{C}}\$.)

For \$R_{_\text{B}}=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$V_{_\text{CC}}=10\:\text{V}\$, these work out \$V_{_\text{E}}\approx 4.926\:\text{V}\$, \$I_{_\text{E}}\approx 4.1052\:\text{mA}\$, \$I_{_\text{E}}\approx 4.0615\:\text{mA}\$, and \$I_{_\text{B}}\approx 43.7\:\mu\text{A}\$.

Separately, you could also do all of the above using two KCL equations, instead. The first is the same as earlier, except that we apply \$I_{_\text{E}}=I_{_\text{B}} +I_{_\text{C}}\$ to the earlier KVL:

$$V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{B}}\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{BE}}-R_{_\text{E}}\cdot \left(I_{_\text{B}} +I_{_\text{C}}\right)=0\:\text{V}$$

And then add this second KVL equation:

$$V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot I_{_\text{C}}-V_{_{\text{CE}_\text{SAT}}}-R_{_\text{E}}\cdot \left(I_{_\text{B}} +I_{_\text{C}}\right)=0\:\text{V}$$

Solving those two equations to find the two unknowns, the base and collector currents, then provides you with exactly the same answers as shown above. Just using an entirely different approach to get there.

### Summary

Since you have a range of values for the base resistor, you need to examine each case, separately, in order to decide about *active* vs *saturated* modes for the BJT. Then, you can work out the solutions for each case based upon that determination.

If you want to create a function that tells you whether or not things are in saturation, you can do that. It is in *active* mode when:

$$V_{_\text{CC}}-R_{_\text{C}}\cdot \beta\cdot I_{_\text{B}}-R_{_\text{E}}\cdot \left(\beta+1\right)\cdot I_{_\text{B}}\ge V_{_\text{BE}}$$

Solving that yields this test:

$$R_{_\text{B}}\ge \beta\cdot R_{_\text{C}}$$

From this, you can make an educated guess that unless \$R_{_\text{B}}\ge 180\:\text{k}\Omega\$, the BJT will be saturated.

Let's test that idea:

[image]

And here you can see that with \$R_{_\text{B}}= 180\:\text{k}\Omega\$ the voltage difference between the collector and emitter remains fairly stable at about one \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$, as predicted, keeping the BJT out of saturation until the DC sweep voltage gets too low to even sustain the \$V_{_\text{BE}}\$ value, anymore.

We can choose to step the **RB** value, but now let's make it go from values that are *less* than the predicted minimum to *more* to make this point stick better:

[image]

Now, in this case, you can see that when \$R_{_\text{B}}= 120\:\text{k}\Omega\$, it rapidly transitions towards our predicted saturation voltage and then sits there over most of the DC sweep range. When \$R_{_\text{B}}= 150\:\text{k}\Omega\$, it more gradually transitions towards our predicted saturation voltage. But then it also sits there for the rest of the DC sweep range.

But once it reaches the predicted value (or higher), you can see that the collector-emitter voltage is at or well above the minimum difference.

Just to nail it down, you can see that when I specify \$175\:\text{k}\Omega\$, that the red line stays nice and flat over the DC sweep range:

[image]

Smaller values lead to saturation. Larger values lead towards active mode. So the prediction function mentioned above is quite accurate. The only factor here is that LTspice uses a more sophisticated model than I did in the above analysis. But the highly simplified model I used gets a result that is still very close to the more sophisticated numerical analysis used by Spice programs.

Comment: Very good information jonk. Just to simplify: Considering that usually the voltage drop between base and emitter is 0.7V, your explanation of a saturated transistor would mean that the transistor is saturated if the Vce Is lower than 0.7V? Right?

Comment: @VictorTito Yes, as that means the base-collector junction is forward biased, which is the beginning of saturation. (If you assume that the base-emitter voltage is 700 mV, which it rarely actually is. But for these purposes, it's good enough.)

Comment: @jonk I will look into this solutions later again. I want to ask some questions about it.

Comment: @Mert Sounds good.