# Transistor working region hypothesis

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

In the following circuit of a transistor I know that \$V_A = 2.5V\$.

How do I know in which zone the transistor is operating?
As I understand it, I should make an hypothesis into one of the working regions until it either contradicts or validates itself. I've tried reading some questions here and articles on the web (and I get the exmplanation/theory) but I get stuck every time I try to do an exercise by my own.

In theory I know I should do that, but I get really confused when applying, and I wonder if there's a way to "click" and make the approach more systematic or obvious, because I freeze every time I see a transistor problem like this and don't know what to do (how to start).

Also, as a side question (semi-related), is there any practical difference when approaching these transistor problems if its BJT or NPN type?

[image]

Comment: It's a PNP Emitter Follower. so you can look up those features

Comment: ludicrous, have you looked at [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/601880/38098) from me, yet? And when you write *"... BJT or NPN type"* did you actually mean PNP or NPN?

Comment: Is this too simple for you ? http://i.stack.imgur.com/SUVkh.png If not then re-read how transistors work.

Comment: e.g. page 92 http://www.apple1.fr/student_manual_for_the_art_of_electronics.pdf

Comment: Do those guess and check exercises with diodes first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing I do is look at the topology surrounding the BJT. Sometimes, it is pretty obvious that the BJT is being used as a switch, which means I'll likely find, if I look for it, that the BJT is operated in *saturated* mode. Sometimes, it is equally obvious that the BJT is being used as a signal amplifier. And there, if I look for it, I expect to see the BJT operated in *active* mode.

Regardless, if I am bothering to try and find out and also if there is a collector load of some kind (if the collector is tied directly to a rail it is most likely active mode), I will *start* with the assumption of *active* mode and apply KVL from base circuit through the BJT and through its emitter circuit, solving for either the base or emitter current equation. I'll plug in the values and work out the emitter current. Then I'll use the simplifying assumption that the collector current is about the same as the emitter current and apply it to the collector load to figure out the voltage difference across the load. If this pushes the collector close to the emitter (with a volt or less) then I have determined it is *not* in active mode and is probably operating saturated -- likely as a switch.

That's about it.

In your example, your collector is tied to a rail. So, in general, this pretty much tells you that the mode is *active*. But let's prove it, just the same.

In your example, the KVL says \$2.5\:\text{V} + \mid i_{_\text{B}}\mid\cdot R_{_\text{B}}+\mid v_{_\text{BE}}\,\mid+\left(\beta+1\right)\mid i_{_\text{B}}\mid\cdot R_{_\text{E}}=5\:\text{V}\$ or put another way: \$\mid\, i_{_\text{B}}\mid\:=\frac{5\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}-\mid\, v_{_\text{BE}}\,\mid}{R_{_\text{B}}+\left(\beta+1\right)\,\cdot\, R_{_\text{E}}}=\frac{5\:\text{V}-2.5\:\text{V}-500\:\text{mV}}{10\:\text{k}\Omega+\left(29+1\right)\,\cdot\, 1\:\text{k}\Omega}=50\:\mu\text{A}\$.

So the voltage drop across \$R_{_\text{B}}\$ will be \$500\:\text{mV}\$ making the base voltage \$3\:\text{V}\$ and the emitter voltage \$3.5\:\text{V}\$. This emitter voltage is \$3.5\:\text{V}\$ above the BJT's collector, which for a PNP means the BJT is in active mode.

We can also now compute the current in \$R_{_\text{E}}\$ to be \$1.5\:\text{mA}\$ (\$\frac{5\:\text{V}-3.5\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{k}\Omega}\$), which we could also have figured out by multiplying 30 (\$\beta+1\$) by the base current we earlier computed.

But you can avoid all that drudgery. The only way \$v_{_\text{A}}\$ can saturate that BJT circuit is by dragging down its emitter to within something slightly less (in magnitude) than a volt of ground -- say \$v_{_\text{E}}\lt +400\:\text{mV}\$ to just make up such a condition while putting a value to it. If so, the emitter current would have to be \$4.6\:\text{mA}\$ and this means that the base current would have to be greater than \$155\:\mu\text{A}\$ (thereabouts.) That means the base resistor dropping \$1.55\:\text{V}\$ and therefore \$v_{_\text{A}}\lt -1.6\:\text{V}\$. Actually, the details start to get more nuanced there because the BE junction voltage won't be \$500\:\text{mV}\$ anymore -- it will larger in magnitude. And worse still, when a BJT goes into saturation, effective \$\beta\$ is much less, meaning that the required base current is just that much larger than expected, meaning that the drop across the base resistor is even more, meaning that a still *more* negative \$v_{_\text{A}}\$ would be likely required.

Comment: You never cease to amaze me with such a comprehensive and insightful explanation. I'm start getting it now, thank you!

Comment: In Linear Region is the voltage drop \$V_{BC}\$ always 0.7V independently of \$i_B\$? And if the transistor were operating in Saturation Mode, would the drop voltage at \$V_{EC}\$ always be 0.1V independently of the \$i_B\$ current (provided it's enough that it is saturated)? So are those always "fixed" for those modes of operation?

Comment: @ludicrous I think you mean that *linear*=*active*? Is that right? In any case, when in *active* mode the BJT's collector looks like a current source/sink (infinite impedance.) When in *saturation* mode, the BJT's collector looks like a voltage source (zero impedance.) There is a tiny region between the two where the BJT is transitioning between these two states. That's perhaps called "soft saturation." In short, when the collector is pulled close to the emitter, the BJT is in saturation and the collector looks like a voltage source.

Comment: @ludicrous  When the collector is far away from the emitter -- any case where the collector is not between the base and emitter voltages and is instead outside that range, though closer to the base than to the emitter, then it is in active mode and the collector looks like a current source. Usually, the only way the collector gets pushed close to the emitter voltage is if there is a collector load that is non-zero. That's why if you see the collector tied to a voltage source (zero load, so to speak), chances are it is in active mode.

Comment: Jonk, something that is still confusing me: if I assume the transistor is working in the Direct Active Region, then \$\beta i_B = i_C\$. I calculate the current \$i_B = .25 mA\$, then the current through \$i_C\$ should be \$7.5 mA\$, right? But the applied voltage at \$C\$ is only 5V, and \$\frac{5}{1.0} = 5.0 mA\$. So is this a contradiction? Is the transistor "imposing" the voltage that restitutes the "missing" current? Or it is I who is missing something? :)

Comment: @ludicrous Yes, it's about 7.5 mA if the beta is about 30. Where did you get the 1.2 to divide into 5? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm sorry, It is \$1k\Omega\$. But then if the voltage source is only 5V it can only produce 5mA of current through a \$1k \Omega\$ resistor. Then where does the resultant 2.5mA come from?

Comment: @ludicrous Where did you get the 0.25 mA at the base?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to do the calculations by myself without reading your calculations part (just reading the aside part of the answer) and then confirm, and now I see where I was mistaken. So I can have no resistor at B that current $i_B$ is also influenced by the collector, right?

Comment: @ludicrous Not true. If the collector voltage is somehow forced close to the emitter voltage, then the base current is ***definitely*** influenced. A way to explain why this happens (not perfect, but close enough) is to realize that the BC junction becomes ***forward-biased***!!! So now you have ***two*** forward-biased diodes to feed. (There's more accurate explanations, but that one suffices in a pinch.)

Comment: I see. If the transistor however were in saturation mode (supposing conditions were met), the current from the Emitter to the Collector would "be influenced" with the \$V_{CEsat}\ = 0.1V\$? So a KVL equation for E-C in that case would be \$-5+R_Ei_E+V_{ECsat} = 0\$? Would the current \$i_C\$ differ from the current \$i_E\$ in that case? Could I say they are equal in saturation? Also, in saturation would \$V_{BEon}\$ still be the voltage across the Base and Emitter?

Comment: @ludicrous In saturation, you can certainly do KVL from collector voltage source, through collector load to collector pin, then to emitter, then to emitter load and finally to emitter voltage source, as the EC pins now look like a voltage source between them.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is to just START. When you see something like this and don't know what to do, start writing out equations until something comes together.

You know the voltage Va, and you know that the voltage at the base will be dropped by Rb multiplied by the current going through Rb. You know the relationship between that base current and the collector current by beta. You know if that current goes through Re it will create a voltage drop. Write those equations down. Use KVL and KCL. They're all simple algebra.

When it comes to non-linear elements like the PNP, when you don't know the region of operation: ASSUME IT. That's right, you can just say "it's in forward active" and then continue to solve your equations. If you get numbers that make sense, then your assumption was correct. If you end up with 1mA = 3mA, that obviously makes no sense and you know your assumption was wrong.

With practice you notice patterns and your assumptions are correct more often than not. That's the game, get better at not being bad. Engineers and professors with 30+ years experience make stupid mistakes and assumptions all the time.

Comment: As in *Fake It til you make it!*

Answer (score 5):

NPN operates just the same as PNP except it's inverted.

You can simplify this problem a lot.

Most of the time, you don't even need to know β to analyze a simple transistor circuit.

In this case, you don't even have to know the rise in voltage for the base resistor.  Assume it's zero then check your assumption later.

Let's assume \$V_B= 2.5V\$ so the emitter rise is given as Veb=0.5V (just the opposite subscript for NPN = Vbe) so \$V_E=3.0V\$

So if Re is 3V then the current must be around 2V/ 10k = 200 uA.  That means the base current is roughly 3% of this across 1k proving the initial assumption was good enough as it is only about a 6.5mV drop are Rb.

[image]

Comment: Rb is 10k and Re is 1k.

Comment: TY @PStechPaul  '>{  It was Murphy's Law. If Veb= 0.5V then Ic must be around 200 uA because when it's 1.5mA, one may expect Veb > 0.6V

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If the transistor were operating in Saturation Mode, would the drop voltage at \$V_{EC}\$ always be 0.1V independently of the \$i_B\$ current? And in linear region is the voltage drop \$V_{BC}\$ always be 0.7V independently of \$i_B\$?

Comment: Yet Emitter Followers will never saturate if the collector R is much smaller or 0 Ohms as in this example with emitter output.

Comment: Not really. Saturation here means collector-base PN junction becomes forward biased just like base-emitter which reduces hFE rapidly towards the rated Ic/Ib=10 . With this condition collector-emitter voltage depends on the "switch like" characteristic and bulk resistance times collector current. In saturation ec/c=Rec or Rce
 as a switch has an effective R value which reduces with increasing bulk chip size and power rating. E.g, the PN2222A NPN is around 1 Ohm in saturation (ballpark) so the low value of 0.1 V often used rises with Ic*Rce

Answer (score 3):

The way I approach such problems is to make an assumption and see if it fits. The transistor looks like an emitter follower, so it should be in the linear region. We'll need to check whether it's saturated or not, and that's all.

Let's assume linear operation, and see whether we can confirm linear operation by excluding saturation.

The equivalent circuit from emitter to base looks as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg0559.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CCCS1 models the current gain. We can write the following equations based on Ohm's law for R_E and R_B:

$$\begin{aligned}
V_A &= 5 - R_E \cdot I_B \cdot (\beta+1) \\
V_B &= 2.5 + R_B \cdot I_B \\
\end{aligned}$$
We also know that $$V_A=V_B+0.5.$$

We can solve those for \$I_B\$:
$$\begin{aligned}
5 - R_E \cdot I_B \cdot (\beta+1) &= 0.5 + 2.5 + R_B \cdot I_B \\
2 - I_B \cdot R_E \cdot (\beta+1) &= I_B \cdot R_B\\
2 &= I_B (R_E \cdot (\beta+1) + R_B) \\
I_B &= 2 (R_E \cdot (\beta+1) + R_B)^{-1} \\
\boxed{I_B} &= 2 (1{\rm k} \cdot 30 + 10{\rm k}) = 2/4\cdot 10^{-4} = 50\mu \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now we can check for saturation:
$$ \boxed{V_{EC}} = V_A-0 = 5 - R_E\cdot I_B \cdot (\beta+1) = 5 - 1{\rm k}\cdot 50\mu \cdot 30 = 3.5.$$

Since \$V_{EC} \gg V_{ECsat}\$, the transistor is not saturated.

The simulation agrees to a reasonable degree:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f84lag.png)</sup>

Comment: Coincidentally same process but more elegant and meters

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder, but I’m writing some of those out having high school students in mind, thus going through some algebra just to make things hopefully clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a datasheet you can draw the load line.Your configuration is a emitter follower -> the BJT will never reach saturation as long as VA>0.